# Good idea to design go back button in modal

Tags: modal-windows, modal

I  need some directions, currently I have a list, if I click one of the items, one modal is shown with information about the item previously selected, and a list of its children, so if I click one of its children the modal information is updated, I mean, the modal shows information of children previously selected, so in the modal I have a button that close it. I just want to change that button to go back, so if I click go back the modal information will update and show previously information, I mean information of parent....

Have you ever encountered this problem?

Comment: This forum works best if you illustrate your current situation and your efforts so far. Visuals help show the larger context; the density of your UI, other competing elements, etc. This will make the answers more valuable to you, as well as others encountering a similar problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly the list is not a list but a tree (since an item has children) to show details in a modal and then changing context within the modal seems very confusing to me.

Is a modal to show details the only way to show details of a list item?
Would it be possible to show the list as tree?
How is the list used? Du users often have to see details of a child item?
How many child items are there?
Does a child item have also children?
etc.

Not knowing the answer to the questions above and assuming the modal has to be a modal I would suggest the following.

If the list which triggers the modal is a list only and not a tree show the tree within the modal and use a master detail pattern. Use one part of the screen for the tree and one part for the details of the selected node. This way it is not necessary to have a back button an the context is always visible.

[image]